# Value update after finishing typing

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to update value after finishing the typing in input?

In Knockout [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) is mentioned that there are 3 options for valueUpdate. Is there any other option to update value after finishing typing (focus out of the input)?

I made it with hasFocus but I have too many inputs and for each I have to create a dedicated variable.

Comment: Yeah, just don't use `valueUpdate`. The default is to use the `change` event which should happen when you shift focus. The [hello world](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) example does this.

Comment: Unfortunately It's not working in my cas, because I have a custom binding :(

Comment: Then that's a problem with your custom binding. You have to attach whatever event handlers you need when you create the binding. This is explained [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#modifying-observables-after-dom-events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it.
Please find my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/60PMdXX0H8ysJcg01KsA?p=preview)
I have custom binding on my second input and on result (which is computed).
In data-bind on second input I add this code:

```
event: { focus:function(){$root.outOfFocus(true)},blur: function(){$root.outOfFocus(false)} }
```

I create one additional observable in my View model and one *if* statement in computed:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
self.outOfFocus = ko.observable(false); //new additional observable
self.value = ko.observable();
self.quantity = ko.observable();

self.totalPrice = ko.computed(function() {
    if(self.value() !== undefined && self.quantity() != undefined && !self.outOfFocus()){// if statement
      return self.value() * self.quantity();
    }
});
```

};